# Is it possible to write an iOS application that installs a CA?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I hope this question isn't too dumb.  We have many websites internally that need to be secure.  However, we don't want to have to purchase a Certificate for each from a Trusted CA (certificate authority).  We have our own self made CA.  It works great for windows PC browsers.

Now we need it to work for dozens of iPads (and iPhones). :-(

I'm wondering if it would be possible to write an iOS application that can install our CA on the device so that Safari will trust our website certificates?

If that is possible any pointers would be appreciated greatly!

Thanks!

EV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the Apple Configurator for Mac? This allows you to bulk install profiles on devices. Alternatively you could send out an email with the CA attached and open it on each device. However, I don't think an app would be able to install a CA.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it yet.  If the user simply opens the CA will it give them a very easy install option?

Comment: this is what it looks like: `http://mitmproxy.org/doc/certinstall/ios.html` very user friendly.

Comment: I was going to point out iPhone Configuration Utility for creating the profile, but a closer look reveals that the iPCU functionality has been rolled into Apple Configurator. Great tool.